# Can't delete Facebook and Google in Online Accounts! Where is the config file for Ubuntu Online Accounts located?

Tags: empathy, online-accounts

since today I have an issue with my Ubuntu Online Account Settings. I started Empathy to log into my messengers, but I got an error that Facebook, Google and MSN need an authentication. I tried to delete all of them, but only MSN I was able to delete. Facebook and Google account do nothing. Doesnt matter account is ON/OFF. 
Is there a way by delete a config file and reset Ubuntu Online Accounts in this way?

Comment: I think it might be a due to a bug in Gnome 3.6. I had the same problem and the only workaround I've found so far is **turning off these and creating new Facebook and Google accounts**.

Comment: Have you tried to end **telepathy-haze** process through _System Monitor_?

Comment: You can also Read Related below Post How to Delete Facebook Account Forever - Visit Below Post Link http://www.kingtricks.com/delete-facebook-account-forever/

Answer (score 11):

Your accounts are stored in file

```
~/.config/goa-1.O/accounts.conf
```

It would certainly be a good idea to stop goa-daemon before editing this file...

```
$ killall goa-daemon
```

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem too . It seemed to occur after an upgrade, I could add new accounts, and disable old ones, but unable to remove old accounts using the proper windows. I eventually found that account information appeared to be stored in the directory

```
/home/$USER/.config/libaccounts-glib/  (replace $USER with your username.)
```

There where 3 files in there **accounts.*** ; I removed them all and rebooted the computer, and found all the online accounts where gone, I then re-created the new accounts manually as needed.

This is a bit of a heavy handed approach, so if you use it, I recommend you take a copy of the files before you remove them from that directory.

Comment: For a softer way, you might consider opening (and editing) the `accounts.db` file with `sqlitebrowser`. Check out the `Accounts` table, remove unneeded records and the write the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the following?

From https://help.ubuntu.com/14.10/ubuntu-help/accounts-remove.html

> 1. Click the icon at the far right of the menu bar and select System Settings.
> 2. Open Online Accounts.
> 3. Select the account you wish to remove.
> 4. Click the Remove Account button in the lower-right portion of the window.
> 5. Click Remove.

Answer (score 1):

A great way to find files is to use the find command and to pipe it to grep.

```
$ cd /
$ find . | grep online-accounts
./usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts
./usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
./usr/lib/evolution-data-server/registry-modules/module-online-accounts.so
./usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libonline-accounts.so
./usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/online-accounts.ui
./usr/share/applications/gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop
./usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/gnome-online-accounts.mo
./usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/gnome-online-accounts.mo
./usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-control-center:gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop
./usr/share/doc/gnome-online-accounts
./usr/share/doc/gnome-online-accounts/copyright
./usr/share/doc/gnome-online-accounts/changelog.Debian.gz
./usr/share/doc/gnome-online-accounts/NEWS.gz
./var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-online-accounts.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-online-accounts.md5sums
```

I don't know much about the online accounts and mine get deleted correctly. Try updating your system and trying again, otherwise you can try and find the files. Apologies for not being able to answer your question directly.

NOTE: if you are getting a permission denied error trying prepending sudo to your commands.

Comment: I tried all founded locations, but sadly no luck. I reinstalled Gnome-Online-Accounts and Online-Account-Setting from the USC > Still the same issue. Could it be so hard to figure out where this information Google and Facebook is located?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove online accounts by using dconf editor.

Open dconf-editor using either terminal or the application menu in unity. Navigate the menu items as:

**com>canonical>unity>webapps**

Select **allowed-domains** and you should see the installed webapps listed there.
Simply delete the list to make it empty.

If that doesn't do it, using dconf-editor, navigate to:

**com>canonical>indicator>messages**

Select **applications** and remove all webapps listed there as well.

Finally, the configuration files are all stored at:

`/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/`  (replace $USER with your username.)

You can try deleting them all and then restart (just to be safe)

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing the same as mentioned on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/1168146 where you can also find the solution. Do:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-google
```

in terminal... and then go back to Online Accounts to remove the entries.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can very easily delete your Facebook and Google account. All you need to do is to just log in to the account and go the privacy settings and delete your account.

Comment: Irrelevant and poorly constructed answer. Answers a different question than the one that was asked.