# How to remove a faulty server connection from Nautilus?

Tags: networking, server, nautilus, 19.04, webdav

While trying to connect to a WebDAV server (Nextcloud) I added a faulty address on accident. [(See screenshot).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ms4V.png) This address obviously connects to nowhere, so clicking on it does nothing but bring up an error message. I then tried to remove this faulty connection from the Nautilus sidebar via right click > remove, but the "remove" option is greyed out.

How do I remove the faulty connection from the sidebar?

EDIT: This is the output from /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=eca43126-c653-4637-8917-0be9e08f40d7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=4A73-C064  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I also tried unmounting the server manually using *gio mount -u* since the "volume" in question is correctly listed with *gio mount -l*.
This doesn't produce the desired result, though ("mount point not found").

Comment: please edit your question and paste the output of `cat /etc/fstab`, a line may have been added to this file. If so, the fix will simply be to delete the line

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added the output to my original post.

Comment: How did you add that address? Did you look in Settings -> Online Accounts? Did you try rebooting your computer or restarting `nautilus` using `nautilus -q` from terminal or Alt-F2?

Comment: Removing all Nextcloud settings from Settings > Online Accounts somehow did the trick! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nextcloud connection is saved in Online Accounts from Ubuntu.

If you [remove the account](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/accounts-remove.html.en) from Settings -> Online Accounts, the faulty mount should go away.

You might need to restart.

Comment: I found this solution to be helpful, the account did reappear after being removed. 

[Delete Gnome Online Account manually][1]


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/245652/cant-delete-facebook-and-google-in-online-accounts-where-is-the-config-file-fo